# Writing files in java, changing case and number

Tags: java, java-io

I'm writing a program that imports a text file and creates an output file by doing the following:

- Reverse case of all letters in input.txt and show up in output.txt.
- Digits will show up as a hyphen-separated list of words for digits in number.(Ex 123 = one - two - three).
- Also the line number should be displayed to the console.

input.txt is as followed:

```
Here is A TEXT
File To Be
Processed FOR Lab09.
There are now 3459 ways to
DESIGN this kind of PROGRAM.
Here's hoping you can figure OUT 1, 2,
or 3 of these designs -
Or AT LEAST come close, even if
you don't find all 3459
```

I can't figure out the conversion of `Strings` to `char` with a `FileReader` to print to the console and file correctly. Any help for this new coder would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * CSC110 Java 10am Lab09 Reading
 *
 * Writing Files file will create output file of the text formatted a certain way.
 */
public class Lab09 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name of file: ");
    String fileName = input.next();
    System.out.println();

    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
      char c = fileInput.next().charAt(0);
      String numberToWord = "";
      pw.println(fileInput.nextLine().toUpperCase());

      if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        System.out.println(fileInput.nextLine().toUpperCase());
        pw.println(fileInput.nextLine().toUpperCase());
      } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        System.out.println(fileInput.nextLine().toLowerCase());

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
          switch (c) {
            case '1':
              numberToWord = numberToWord + "one";
              pw.println(fileInput.next(numberToWord));
              System.out.println(numberToWord);
              break;

            case '2':
              numberToWord = numberToWord + "two";
              pw.println(fileInput.next(numberToWord));
              System.out.println(numberToWord);
              break;

            case '3':
              numberToWord = numberToWord + "three";
              pw.println(fileInput.next(numberToWord));
              System.out.println(numberToWord);
              break;

            case '4':
              numberToWord = numberToWord + "four";
              pw.println(fileInput.next(numberToWord));
              System.out.println(numberToWord);
              break;

            case '5':
              numberToWord = numberToWord + "five";
              pw.println(fileInput.next(numberToWord));
              System.out.println(numberToWord);
              break;

            case '6':
              numberToWord = numberToWord + "six";
              pw.println(fileInput.next(numberToWord));
              System.out.println(numberToWord);
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    pw.close();
    fileInput.close();
  }
}
```

Sorry its tough to look at! I just need some guidance! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strings to char? "String".toCharArray(); or similar should be enough. either way, I would recommend getting rid of repetitive code, it only makes it harder to reafd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an array for each number

```
String nums [] = {"zero", "one", "two"};  // etc
```

and then test if the char is a number, and if so substract the ascii of '0'

```
char c = '2';

if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    int index = c - '0';
    System.out.println(nums [index]);
}
```